# Could not transfer artifact from/to central because of InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: eclipse, maven, ssl-certificate, truststore, maven-resources-plugin

When I try to install the `pom.xml` of maven project, I get the following error. Please help.

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project pm: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Comment: I am having the same problem... but haven't found a solution yet :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when compiling on a remote CI server. In the end, forcing the location of the trustStore when compiling with Maven solved the problem for me:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

The actual path will be different based on your JDK installation.

I speculate (not sure) that the problem arises if you have more than one JDK, some old one does not have proper certificate, and somehow Maven picks up that old one even if you are using the right `javac`

Comment: I've got the same problem (as of 2 days ago on shippable.com builds) but this isn't making a difference (on JDK 11).  Mine looks to be an issue with the keystore format, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1739631 #4 onwards

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, found
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/osv-dev/wFzT12-p2bw/vT42CiuOBQAJ
which recommended

```sh
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
$ sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
$ sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Worked first try for me, so leaving it here if anyone else stumbles upon this.